# How do I call a method from another class in an onCreate method?

Tags: java, android

Java: in android SDK
How do I call a method from another class in an `onCreate()` method?

LOGCAT:

```
08-28 22:27:24.152: W/dalvikvm(13642): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.valgriz.high.low/com.valgriz.high.low.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at com.valgriz.high.low.Package.runThis(Package.java:16)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at com.valgriz.high.low.Game.onCreate(Game.java:34)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Looks like whatever object you are calling findViewById() on is null. Is it possible to post your onCreate() method or just part of it?

Comment: If you follow the stack trace from the top down you can see that before findViewById is the method com.valgriz.high.low.Package.runThis (). If you can post source it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main );

    MyClass work = new MyClass();
    work.doSomething();

}

public class MyClass{

    public void doSomething(){
        Log.d("tag", "yes sir!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Obtain an instance of that class and call the method.

Or if the method is static access it through the class name.

There are some restrictions in Android based on whether the method does something to the UI or accesses data structures that are set up after the onCreate() method. If you include some more detail as to what you are trying to do, you'll probably get some more accurate help.

If you have no idea what I'm talking, start Googling

Comment: I know how to call a method in Java.  But when I program an app it gives me errors.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: post the logcat of the error and the code of what you're trying to do. We need a little more to work off of.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare and instantiate the class object or call it depending on whether or not it is static.

```
private NonStaticObject dynamicObject;
private StaticObject stObject;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //instantiate the non static object
    dynamicObject = new NonStaticObject();
    dynamicObject.method();

    //or simply call the static method.
    stObject.method();

}
```

Comment: The above is just a sample of how to call the methods.  You would need to create the NonStaticObject and StaticObject naming them how you wish or use existing framework objects.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs (snippet below), it looks like you are trying to find a view using a wrong id *or* a view which is not present / instantiated / created / has been removed.

```
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at com.valgriz.high.low.Package.runThis(Package.java:16)
08-28 22:27:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13642):    at com.valgriz.high.low.Game.onCreate(Game.java:34)
```

Please check if the creation of the view that you are trying to find is complete and you are referring to it using the correct id.

Also, as per the [android docs (transcript below)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) for `onCreate(Bundle)` should satisfy the below condition. Please check if you are making a call to the parent using `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` from the first line of the `onCreate(Bundle)` method of *Game* class.

> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // call method from other class
    myclass Objectc = new myclass();
    Objectc.methodA();
}
```